# Trying to use prepared statement with sql like keyword but running into problems

Tags: mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am taking form input and trying to pass it to a sql select query using the `LIKE` keyword along with the `%` modifier all within a *pdo prepared statement* and I have no idea where to start debugging. Here's the code:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $search_string = "%".$_POST["search"]."%";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_tags LIKE :a";

    $stmt = $connect->link->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(":a",$search_string);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetchall()) {
        echo $row["post_tags"];
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: post_tags in C:\wamp64\www\cms\CMS_TEMPLATE\includes\sidebar.php on line 18

Comment: So then there is no column called `post_tags` in the `post_tags` table!!

Comment: What are the names of the columns in the `post_tags` page

Comment: [2 Accounts! Tut tut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595005/trying-to-count-rows-of-a-prepared-statement-search-set?noredirect=1#comment103503132_58595005)

Comment: it gives that error with every column i try it is correct

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i was using fetchall instead of fetch

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                $search_string = "%".$_POST["search"]."%";
                ;

                $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_tags LIKE :a";

                $stmt = $connect->link->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bindValue(":a",$search_string);
                $stmt->execute();

                $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();
                echo $numrows;

                    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                        echo $row["post_tags"];
                    }



            }
```